Create a custom Pydantic class requiring value to be in an interval?
I'm working to build a function parameter validation library using pydantic. We want to be able to validate parameters' types and values. Types are easy enough, but I'm having a hard time creating a class to validate values. Specifically, the first class I want to build is one that requires the value to be in a user-defined interval.
So far, I've written a decorator and a function-based version of ValueInInterval. However, I would prefer to use a class-based approach. Here's an MRE of my issue:
from typing import Any
from typing_extensions import Annotated
from pydantic import Field, validate_call


class ValueInInterval:
    def __init__(
        self,
        type_definition: Any,
        start: Any,
        end: Any,
        include_start: bool = True,
        include_end: bool = True,
    ):
        self.type_definition = type_definition
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.include_start = include_start
        self.include_end = include_end

    def __call__(self):
        return Annotated[self.type_definition, self.create_field()]

    def create_field(self) -> Field:
        field_config = {}
        if self.include_start:
            field_config.update({"ge": self.start})
        else:
            field_config.update({"gt": self.start})
        if self.include_end:
            field_config.update({"le": self.end})
        else:
            field_config.update({"lt": self.end})

        return Field(**field_config)

    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(
        self,
        handler,
    ):
        schema = handler(self.type_definition)

        if self.include_start:
            schema.update({"ge": self.start})
        else:
            schema.update({"gt": self.start})

        if self.include_end:
            schema.update({"le": self.end})
        else:
            schema.update({"lt": self.end})

        return schema


@validate_call()
def test_interval(
    value: ValueInInterval(type_definition=int, start=1, end=10),
):
    print(value)


test_interval(value=1)  # should succeed
test_interval(value=0)  # should fail

Running this code in the PyCharm's Python console, I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
  File "<input>", line 56, in <module>
  File "C:\projects\django-postgres-loader\venv\lib\site-packages\pydantic\validate_call_decorator.py", line 56, in validate
    validate_call_wrapper = _validate_call.ValidateCallWrapper(function, config, validate_return, local_ns)
  File "C:\projects\django-postgres-loader\venv\lib\site-packages\pydantic\_internal\_validate_call.py", line 57, in __init__
    schema = gen_schema.clean_schema(gen_schema.generate_schema(function))
  File "C:\projects\django-postgres-loader\venv\lib\site-packages\pydantic\_internal\_generate_schema.py", line 512, in generate_schema
    schema = self._generate_schema_inner(obj)
  File "C:\projects\django-postgres-loader\venv\lib\site-packages\pydantic\_internal\_generate_schema.py", line 789, in _generate_schema_inner
    return self.match_type(obj)
  File "C:\projects\django-postgres-loader\venv\lib\site-packages\pydantic\_internal\_generate_schema.py", line 856, in match_type
    return self._callable_schema(obj)
  File "C:\projects\django-postgres-loader\venv\lib\site-packages\pydantic\_internal\_generate_schema.py", line 1692, in _callable_schema
    arg_schema = self._generate_parameter_schema(name, annotation, p.default, parameter_mode)
  File "C:\projects\django-postgres-loader\venv\lib\site-packages\pydantic\_internal\_generate_schema.py", line 1414, in _generate_parameter_schema
    schema = self._apply_annotations(source_type, annotations)
  File "C:\projects\django-postgres-loader\venv\lib\site-packages\pydantic\_internal\_generate_schema.py", line 1890, in _apply_annotations
    schema = get_inner_schema(source_type)
  File "C:\projects\django-postgres-loader\venv\lib\site-packages\pydantic\_internal\_schema_generation_shared.py", line 83, in __call__
    schema = self._handler(source_type)
  File "C:\projects\django-postgres-loader\venv\lib\site-packages\pydantic\_internal\_generate_schema.py", line 1869, in inner_handler
    from_property = self._generate_schema_from_property(obj, source_type)
  File "C:\projects\django-postgres-loader\venv\lib\site-packages\pydantic\_internal\_generate_schema.py", line 677, in _generate_schema_from_property
    schema = get_schema(source)
  File "<input>", line 40, in __get_pydantic_core_schema__
TypeError: __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I strongly suspect that I've not written the __get_pydantic_core_schema__ correctly. Note that I'm using pydantic version 2.7 and Python 3.11.

@mkrieger1 I could use that syntax if the bounds were the same every time (I have such types for, e.g., positive integers). But the idea here is that the user provides bounds and then I dynamically create the Field syntax you describe based on that input (this is what the create_field  method is doing in my class).
EDIT: I don't see the comment anymore. It said (more or less): "That is complicated. Why not just use Field(ge=..., le=...)?"

I saw that you already use Field with ge and le internally and deleted my comment.

I was able to find a solution - I had indeed messed up when writing the __get_pydantic_core_schema__ method. Instead of calling handler as a function, its .generate_schema() method must be used, i.e. I replaced
schema = handler(self.type_definition)

with
schema = handler.generate_schema(self.type_definition)

So here is the full class definition that I ultimately went with:
from typing import Any, Union
from typing_extensions import Annotated
from pydantic import Field, GetCoreSchemaHandler, validate_call
from pydantic_core import core_schema


class ValueInInterval:
    def __init__(
        self,
        type_definition: Any,
        start: Any = None,
        end: Any = None,
        include_start: bool = True,
        include_end: bool = True,
    ):
        self.type_definition = type_definition
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.include_start = include_start
        self.include_end = include_end

    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(
        self,
        source_type,
        handler,
    ):
        schema = handler.generate_schema(self.type_definition)

        if self.start is not None:
            if self.include_start:
                schema.update({"ge": self.start})
            else:
                schema.update({"gt": self.start})

        if self.end is not None:
            if self.include_end:
                schema.update({"le": self.end})
            else:
                schema.update({"lt": self.end})

        return schema


# usage example
@validate_call()
def test_interval(
    value: ValueInInterval(type_definition=int, start=1, end=10),
):
    print(value)

test_interval(value=1) # passes
test_interval(value=0) # fails


Your answer could be improved by explaining what was wrong with your first __get_pydantic_core_schema__ method. Or did it require a complete rewrite?

Good call - I've edited my answer. Fortunately, not a full rewrite - just had to modify the line where I initialized the schema object.

You could implement a factory for you model to achieve the desired behaviour:
import pydantic


def model_factory(type_: type, ge: int, lt: int):
    class Model(pydantic.BaseModel):
        value: type_ = pydantic.Field(gt=ge, lt=lt)

    return Model


model = model_factory(type_=int, ge=1, lt=10)

model(value=5)  # ok
model(value=0)  # raise ValidationError
model(value="foo")  # raise ValidationError


would be good, if you could add this solution to OP code
